# Search for a specific query (TermsQuery) without type-specific class in NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

First time using ElasticSearch (using NEST as the wrapper). I want to search in an external ElasticSearch database.

I simply want to run a test query towards a specific field called `cvrNummer`. I have the following code, which doesn't compile because: `The type arguments for method 'ElasticSearch.Search<T> .. ', cannot be inferred from the usage.`

I assume it's because I cannot specify the type-specific class. Challenge is I don't know that one.

**My question is**: how do I run the query below, without exactly know what I get back (to make a type-specific model)? And if I need that model, how do I "make" that model when the documentation is lacking?

**My code:**

```
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(_path)).
        BasicAuthentication(_username,_password);

        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var es_query = new TermsQuery
        {
            Name = "named_query",
            Boost = 1.1,
            Field = "cvrNummer",
            Terms = new string[] { "36406208" }
        };

        client.Search(es_query);
```

**Only documentation I have**:

```
curl -u "<brugernavn>:<password>" -XPOST http://URL -d'
{ "from" : 0, "size" : 1,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "cvrNummer": VALUE
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT MORE DATA:**

Document model from documentation:

```
curl -u "<brugernavn>:<password>" -XGET http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-permanent/_mapping
```

**Full search example:**

```
curl -u "<brugernavn>:<password>" -XPOST http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-permanent/_search -d'
{ "from" : 0, "size" : 1,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "cvrNummer": 10961211
    }
  }
}
'
```

Comment: Try something like this: `client.Search<dynamic>(s => s.From(0).Size(1).Query(q => q.Terms(t => t.Name("named_query").Boost(1.1f).Field("cvrNummer").Terms("36406208"))));`

Comment: @Evk Thanks! This results in a: "'Index name is null for the given type and no default index is set. Map an index name using ConnectionSettings.DefaultMappingFor<TDocument>() or set a default index using ConnectionSettings.DefaultIndex().'" . Any idea? :-)

Comment: And how full url in curl "documentation" looks like (the path part, after domain)?

Comment: @Evk Just updated with more data :-) thanks for asking

Comment: Then try to `s => s.From(0).Size(1).Index("cvr-permanent").AllTypes().(... the rest of the above...)`

Comment: @Evk Perfect - that works. I still get "Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST" but that's an error that makes sense (URL doesn't match). I will fix that one. Will you add a quick answer? Then I will mark it as the answer :-)

Comment: Yep. Just got it to work by changing my original path to http://distribution.virk.dk/ without any parameters. Thanks a lot @Evk - solved my problem :-) !

Comment: Did you see the documentation at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert your "documentation" curl request to C# api syntax like this:

```
client.Search<dynamic>(s => s //dynamic because you don't know the structure
    .From(0)
    .Size(1)
    .Index("cvr-permanent") // index you are searching, taken from url of curl
    .AllTypes() // search all types in that index
    .Query(q => q.Terms(t => 
         t.Name("named_query")
        .Boost(1.1f)
        .Field("cvrNummer")
        .Terms("36406208"))));
```

If you don't like `dynamic` - you can use `JObject`, which will be the real type returned by `Search` if you used `dynamic`:

```
var response = client.Search<JObject>(...);
```

Then you can access matched documents like this:

```
foreach (var document in result.Documents) {
    // if you used `JObject`:
    Console.WriteLine(document["account_number"]);
    // if you used `dynamic`:
    Console.WriteLine(document.account_number);
}
```

If you used `JObject` you can also call `ToString()` on the resulting `JObject` (so, `document.ToString()` in the example above) to see full json of returned document, so that you can learn its structure.